# View images in folder

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I am building a windows form in C#. Along the bottom of my form, I would like to have a horizontal row of image thumbnails for all the images in the folder. Ideally, the user could double-click an image and it would open up in the default picture viewer. Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: It would be nice if you would post a question instead of 'i want this, please do it for me'. Where do you have a problem? Whats not working?

Comment: I'm not looking for someone to do it for me. I just have no idea where to begin. Every tutorial I come across for something like this is for building web pages instead of windows forms. Also, since I am teaching myself as I go along, I figured I would come here for some assistance.

Comment: Hey, don't pay attention to comments like this. Why bother writing anything if the comment has no value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can muck around with the ListView control that comes with .Net but here is a tutorial on [ImageListView control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/imagelistview.aspx) by Ozgur Ozcitak. It works very similar to the standard ListView except it can load the images Asynchronously. You can download his project and look at his code or just use the control straight away.